# Dimension of intersection of distinct subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $W_1, W_2, W_3$ be $3$ distinct subspaces of $\Bbb{R}$$^{10}$ such that each $W_i$ has dimension 9.
Let $W  = W_1 \cap W_2 \cap W_3$. Then which of the following can we conclude?

1. $W$ may not be a subspace of $\Bbb{R}$$^{10}$
2. $\dim W \le 8$
3. $\dim W \ge 7$
4. $\dim W \le 3$

I know that first and fourth options are incorrect. I have even find examples where dimension of W is $7$ and $8$.

But still from here, how can I conclude that the third option is correct. I know that dimension of $W$ should be less than or equal to $9$. It can't be $9$ since those subspaces are distinct. So second option will be correct. But how do I know that the dimension of $W$ Will be greater than or equal to $7$?

Comment: Roughly speaking: If you intersect with a codimension 1 subspace, the dimension can drop by at most 1.

Comment: What is c0dimension?..intersection with what?..I didn't understand

Comment: The codimension of a subspace $U\subseteq V$ is $\operatorname{codim}(U)=\dim(V)-\dim(U)$. In your case all $W_i$ are of codimension $1$. It is an easy consequence of the dimension formula, that $\dim(U_1\cap U_2) \ge \dim(U_1) - \operatorname{codim}(U_2)$. Hence $\dim(W_1\cap W_2) \ge 9-1=8$, and indeed we have $=8$ here. Then intersecting with $W_3$ might lower the dimension by at most $1$ again, so you and up with $\dim(W)\ge 7$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any two subspaces $X$ and $Y$ of a vector space $V$ you have
$$
\dim(X+Y) = \dim(X) + \dim(Y) - \dim(X\cap Y).
$$
Starting with $W_1$ and $W_2$ this gives you
$$
\dim(W_1\cap W_2) = \dim(W_1) + \dim(W_2) - \dim(W_1+W_2) = 9 + 9 - 10 = 8,
$$
where $\dim(W_1+W_2)$ is $10$ since the two $9$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^{10}$ are distinct.

Since $W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3$ is a subspace of $W_1\cap W_2$ we immediately conclude
$$
\dim(W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3) \le 8.
$$
Finally
$$
\dim(W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3) = \underbrace{\dim(W_1\cap W_2)}_{{}=8} + \underbrace{\dim(W_3)}_{{}=9} - \dim((W_1\cap W_2) + W_3).
$$
Since $\dim((W_1\cap W_2) + W_3)\le 10$ we can conclude
$$
\dim(W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3) \ge 7.
$$

Answer (score 1):

For each $W_i$ choose a one-dimensional complement $V_i$ such that $\Bbb{R}^{10} = W_i\oplus V_i$. Let $$pr_i : \Bbb{R}^{10} \rightarrow V_i$$ be the projection onto $V_i$. Then we have $$x \in W_i \Leftrightarrow x \in \text{ker } pr_i.$$ Consider the linear map $$T: \Bbb{R}^{10} \rightarrow V_1\oplus V_2 \oplus V_3$$ given by $$T(x) = (pr_1(x), pr_2(x), pr_3(x)).$$ Then $$W = W_1 \cap W_2 \cap W_3 = \text{ker }pr_1 \cap \text{ker }pr_2 \cap \text{ker }pr_3 = \text{ker }T.$$ Since $T$ is a linear map to a 3-dimensional vectorspace, the rank of $T$ is at most $3$. And we get $$\text{dim }W = \text{dim}(\text{ker }T) = 10 - \text{dim}(\text{rank }T) \geq 10 - 3 = 7$$.